# How do I check for bad superblocks and fix them on a USB device in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, usb, fsck, superblock

I've found some instructions for this, but it seems the `fsck` options are outdated.  Currently I am trying:

```
mke2fs -n /dev/sdc4
```

then using the blocks listed in this:

```
fsck -y -b 163840 /dev/sdc4
```

Actually, as I look at the fsck help, it would seem it should work, but when I run it, I get

```
invalid option -- b
```

why isnt this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `e2fsck -y -b 163840 /dev/sdc4`.

`fsck` is just a wrapper to the appropriate checker program for the filesystem. On my 10.04 box fsck does not take a `-b` option, but `e2fsck` does.

Comment: perfect, thanks man. if anyone else is doing this, it does have to be root